# How to redirect my app to the add contact section

Tags: flutter, dart, url, launch

I'm creating a project where I bring in data from a customer model that has a phone number and I need to be able to add that phone number as a new contact, but I haven't found a way to redirect my app to Add Contact. I have only seen how to redirect calls.

```
Padding(
 padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0),
 child: Container(
  width: 50,
  child: FlatButton(
   child: Icon(Icons.call, color: Color(0xFF7AAF00),),
   onPressed:() async{
   String url = 'tel:${model.cliente.telefono}'; 
   if (await canLaunch(url)) {
    await launch(url);
   }else{
    throw 'No se pudo $url';
   }
  }
 ),
),),


Container(
width: 50,
child: FlatButton(
 child: Icon(Icons.contact_page_outlined, color: Color(0xFF7AAF00),),
  onPressed: (){
  },
),),
```

Answer (score 0):

to add a new Contact to your Phone with Flutter I would suggest using a package from pub dev

[Klick here to view flutter_contact package](http://%20https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_contact)

the package has a function called:

> await Contacts.addContact(newContact);

Depending on what is your goal etc.
Here is a full example from the Package:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:flutter_contact/contacts.dart';
import 'package:flutter_contact/flutter_contact.dart';

class AddContactPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _AddContactPageState();
}

class _AddContactPageState extends State<AddContactPage> {
  Contact contact = Contact();
  PostalAddress address = PostalAddress(label: 'Home');
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Add a contact'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          TextButton(
            onPressed: () {
              _formKey.currentState!.save();
              contact.postalAddresses = [address];
              Contacts.addContact(contact);
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
            },
            child: Icon(Icons.save, color: Colors.white),
          )
        ],
      ),
      body: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
        child: Form(
          key: _formKey,
          child: ListView(
            children: <Widget>[
              TextFormField(
                decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'First name'),
                onSaved: (v) => contact.givenName = v,
              ),
              TextFormField(
                decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Middle name'),
                onSaved: (v) => contact.middleName = v,
              ),
              TextFormField(
                decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Last name'),
                onSaved: (v) => contact.familyName = v,
              ),
              TextFormField(
                decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Prefix'),
                onSaved: (v) => contact.prefix = v,
              ),
              TextFormField(
                decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Suffix'),
                onSaved: (v) => contact.suffix = v,
              ),
              TextFormField(
                decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Phone'),
                onSaved: (v) => contact.phones = [
                  if (v != null && v.isNotEmpty) Item(label: 'mobile', value: v)
                ],
                keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
              ),
              TextFormField(
                decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'E-mail'),
                onSaved: (v) => contact.emails = [
                  if (v != null && v.isNotEmpty) Item(label: 'work', value: v)
                ],
                keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
              ),
              TextFormField(
                decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Company'),
                onSaved: (v) => contact.company = v,
              ),
              TextFormField(
                decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Job'),
                onSaved: (v) => contact.jobTitle = v,
              ),
              TextFormField(
                decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Street'),
                onSaved: (v) => address.street = v,
              ),
              TextFormField(
                decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'City'),
                onSaved: (v) => address.city = v,
              ),
              TextFormField(
                decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Region'),
                onSaved: (v) => address.region = v,
              ),
              TextFormField(
                decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Postal code'),
                onSaved: (v) => address.postcode = v,
              ),
              TextFormField(
                decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Country'),
                onSaved: (v) => address.country = v,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```